# Print Macro either gives me error 1004 or crashes excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to build a a button click print macro to print all but two sheets (currently 5 total sheets). In addition I have a third sheet that I want the user to define how many pages of it to print. When I try to to have it be based off of a cell I get error 1004. To see if the rest of the code works and I make the module have a defined number excel crashes on me after it does the first sheet to print.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Wks As Worksheet, xcell As Integer
'The next line is where I get 1004 but when I change it to a fixed number it crashes excel'
xcell = Sheets("Print Page").Range("B12").Value
If xcell < 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Please Enter the number of pages needed")
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each Wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            If Wks.Name = "Print Page" Then
            Else
                If Wks.Name = "Specs" Then
                Else
                    If Wks.Name = "Data" Then
                    Wks.PrintOut From:=1, To:=xcell
                    Else
                    Wks.PrintOut
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Wks
End If
End Sub
```

There is probably a cleaner way to write this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I can see how you could get errors 6, 9 or 13 on the `xcell =` line, but not the 1004. Is that the actual code you are running?

Comment: Yeah that’s the actual code I’m running

Comment: `PrintOut` method is also causing my Excel to crash when selecting multiple sheets at once. I am on Win10 XL2016

Comment: I’m running OS X excel2016

Comment: Are multiple sheets selected? If that's the case, make sure you ungroup them first.

Comment: Tried the code as it is, ( and also tried with multiple sheets selected) but found working  without any error. I am using excel 2007. may be issue with printer or that particular file..Regarding cleaner way, `if` `else` can be reduced to two by combining with `Or` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure will these work on Mac. Below will keep prompting a value > 0 if that B12 is less than 1. Simplified your worksheet conditions and refers all objects within the workbook the macro is in.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Wks As Worksheet, xcell As Long, sInput As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Worksheets("Print Page").Range("B12")
            xcell = CLng(.Value)
            If xcell < 1 Then
                Do
                    sInput = InputBox("Please Enter the number of pages needed:", "Pages to print", 1)
                    If Len(sInput) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' Abort if clicked Cancel/left empty and clicked OK
                    If IsNumeric(sInput) Then xcell = CLng(sInput)
                Loop Until xcell > 0
                .Value = xcell
            End If
        End With
        For Each Wks In .Worksheets
            If Wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                Select Case Wks.Name
                    Case "Print Page", "Specs" ' Skip!
                    Case "Data"
                        Wks.PrintOut From:=1, To:=xcell
                    Case Else
                        Wks.PrintOut
                End Select
            End If
        Next Wks
    End With
End Sub
```